# Fetching User Info in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller, javascript-controller, helper

I'm trying to create a Lightning Component to integrate Sendbird into Salesforce by following this guide: https://sendbird.com/developer/tutorials/how-to-integrate-sendbird-with-salesforce

I've successfully created this, and it does work using the Salesforce User ID as the Sendbird ID, but ideally I'd like to pass in a custom field from the User record instead. I know that I need an Apex controller for this, and I tried copying from this answer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005PVAQA2) but I can't seem to get it to work properly. It just comes back totally blank. I also tried adding the `doInit` code directly in the `handleMessage` method, and that doesn't work either.

Component:

```
    <aura:component controller="CurrentUserInfoController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    
    <lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilitybar" />
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="this" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    
    <aura:attribute name="userInfo" type="User" />
    
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="String" />
    
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService" />
    
    <lightning:container
                         
                         aura:id="SendBird_Bar"
                         
                         src="{!$Resource.sendbird_bar + '/index.html'}"
                         
                         onmessage="{!c.handleMessage}"
                         
                         />
    
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
    ({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper){
        var action = component.get("c.fetchUser");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.userInfo",storeResponse);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    
    handleMessage: function(component, message, helper) {

    var payload = message.getParams().payload;

    if (payload === "READY") helper.initUIKit(component, message, helper);

  }
});
```

Helper:

```
    ({

  initUIKit: function(component, message, helper) {

      var userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id"); //this works
      //var userId = component.get("c.userInfo").My_Custom_Field__c; //this doesn't
      
      console.log(userId);

      var message = { userId: userId };

    try {

      component.find("SendBird_Bar").message(message);

    } catch (err) {

      console.error("Error from Utilities Bar:", err);

    }

  }

})
```

Apex Controller:

```
    public class CurrentUserInfoController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static User fetchUser(){
        User u = [SELECT Id, Name, My_Custom_Field__c FROM User WHERE Id = :userInfo.getUserId()];
        return u;
    }
    
}
```

How do I fetch the User info and pass my custom field to my helper function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemed to have gotten your [value providers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm) mixed up:

- `c` = A component’s controller, which enables you to wire up event handlers and actions for the component
- `v` = A component’s attribute set. This value provider enables you to access the value of a component’s attribute in the component’s markup.

You appropriately use `c.fetchUser` to use the controller's method to take an action, but you don't want to do the same when accessing your defined attributes.

```
initUIKit: function(component, message, helper) {
    //this doesn't work
    var userId = component.get("c.userInfo").My_Custom_Field__c;
    
    //should be this
    var userId = component.get("v.userInfo").My_Custom_Field__c;
    ...
}
```

---

You also, technically, don't need apex. You could leverage [force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation) combined with setting the appropriate current userId in an attribute during your `init`

```
<aura:attribute name="userRecord" type="Object"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.userId}">
    <force:recordData 
        aura:id="recordLoader"
        recordId="{!v.userId}"
        fields="My_Custom_Field__c"
        targetFields="{!v.userRecord}"
        targetError="{!v.recordLoadError}"
    />
</aura:if>
```

Then, when needed, you can get the user record and access the field you loaded with it.

```
let userCustomField = component.get("v.userRecord").My_Custom_Field__c;
```